# How to set a matrix to 0?

Tags: c, for-loop, matrix

I'm sorry if the question isn't really explanatory. I'm trying to set to 0 that matrix and thanks to the test printf I see that when i is 2 j is set to 0 insted of 3. Where am i wrong?

```
int matrix[3][3];

int i, j;
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
    for(j=0;j<4;j++){
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
        printf("%d\t%d\t%d\n", matrix[i][j], i, j);
    }
}
```

Comment: `int matrix[3][3] = {0};`

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to zero out all the entries, you can use this:

```
memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));
```

You will have to `#include <string.h>`. If the size of the matrix isn't known at compile time by the compiler (it is declared elsewhere), then you can still use this:

```
memset(matrix, 0, rows*cols*sizeof(double));
```

In your case

```
memset(matrix, 0, 3*3*sizeof(double));
```

Answer (score 2):

matrix[3][3] means its index is 0 , 1 and 2

therefore change this

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
for(j=0;j<4;j++){
```

to

```
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is accessing uninitialized memory location, for eg, `matrix[3][3]`. It has indeterminate value and finally invokes undefined behavior.
Change

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

Do same the second loop.
You cam initialize your array to zero by using initializer as

```
int matrix[3][3] = {{0}};
```